# HTML/CSS Lining up divs

Tags: css, html

This is pretty basic CSS question. I have this as my result:

[image]

I want the name and date to be on a single line next to the menu icon

HTML:

```
<div class="topnav">
    <span style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer;" onclick="openNav()">&#9776;</span>
    <div class="topline">
        <div id="name">John Doe</div>
        <div id="date">04/27/2018</div></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.topnav{
    background-color: #3071a9;
    color: #ffffff;
}
.topline{
    padding-left: 20px;
}

#name {
    float:left;
}

#date {
    float:left;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add to your CSS :

```
.topline{
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<span style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer;" onclick="openNav()">&#9776;</span>
```

This needs to be made into a `div` and floated left like your name and date are. You also need topnav to be of the right width (whether it's fixed or not) for everything to fit inside, otherwise it'll be pushed down.

```
    <div style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer;float:left;" onclick="openNav()">&#9776;</div>
```

You could keep it a span by using `display:inline` or `inline-block`, but since you're floating the other divs, might as well keep it consistent. [Display in CSS](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp)

Answer (score 0):

Stop all the floating! Use flexbox instead:

```css
.topnav {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #3071a9;
  color: #ffffff;
}

#name,
#date {
  margin-left: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="topnav">
  <span style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer;" onclick="openNav()">&#9776;</span>
  <div id="name">John Doe</div>
  <div id="date">04/27/2018</div>
</div>
</div>
```